# Python Tkinter use to emulate blinking with interaction of multiple buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, blink

I am looking for a solution to emulate the behavior of the UI of an electronic component and the user interaction (which should be pushing buttons) with LEDs reporting an internal state of the electronic component.

I am using python and the tKinter module to do so.

My code runs and my GUI window displays correctly. However, when I push several times on buttons the behavior is not as expected.

I have 4 possible state for each LED (OFF, ON, (Blinking) SLOW, (Blinking) FAST).
I have 4 buttons which can have an impact on the state. Each button has an interaction function defined in the widget class I have defined, and each of this function, once called, redefines the internal state of the widget.

In order to control the blinking of the LED, I use a single loop and the self.after( ..) function. This function is the following:

```
def toggleLeds(self):
    for led in [self.ledTxIP, self.ledRxIP, self.ledTxRS, self.ledRxRS, self.ledPower, self.ledRun, self.ledStatus, self.ledConfig]:
        if (((led[1] == "SLOW") and (self._FastBlinking == 0)) or (led[1] =="FAST")):
            bg = led[0].cget("background")
            bg = "green" if bg == "black" else "black"
            led[0].configure(background=bg)
        elif((led[1] == "OFF") and (self._update == 1)):
            led[0].configure(background="black")
            self._update = 0
        elif (self._update == 1):
            led[0].configure(background="green")
            self._update = 0
    self._FastBlinking = (self._FastBlinking + 1)%2
    self.update_idletasks()
    self.after(self._FastBlinkTime, self.toggleLeds)
```

This one is called recursively through the self.after function, and at the end of the interaction function I have defined for each button.

Here is how I have defined a single LED:

```
    self.ledTxIP     = [tk.Label(self, width=1, borderwidth=2, relief="groove"),"OFF"]
```

And here is an example of the button interaction function:

```
def pushMode(self):
    if (re.search("Reset",self.state) == None):
        if (self.clickModCnt == 0):
            self.state = "Status"
            self._stateTimer = int(time.gmtime()[5])
        elif (self.clickModCnt == 1):
            if(int(time.gmtime()[5]) - self._stateTimer < 3):
                self.state = "Config"
            else:
                self.state = "RunMode"
        else:
            self.state = "RunMode"
    self.clickModCnt = (self.clickModCnt + 1)%3
    self._update = 1
    self.updateLedState()
```

If anybody has an advice on this, it would be more than welcome.

Comment: It feels like some details are missing.  You say that "the behavior is not as expected," but don't list the behavior itself.  It's also not very clear (to me) what behavior *is* expected when you click the buttons.  You do talk about the LED states, but don't give full details about how those states should be affected by the buttons.

Comment: The expected behavior is that, by pushing buttons, the internal state of the controller should be modified which should be signaled by LEDs (there are 8 of them) either being OFF, steady ON or blinking SLOW or FAST. The unexpected behavior is that I was wishing that when a state change happens (initial state is LED1 is steady ON and LED2 is blinking SLOW, and next state is LED1 blinking SLOW and LED2 still blinking SLOW), the blinking would be synchronous and at a steady frequency for all LEDs.

Comment: However, in this case, when the change happens the frequency of the blinking changes and it does not seem to remain synchronous.

Comment: Just wondering if it is not related to the recursive call `self.after(self._FastBlinkTime, self.toggleLeds)`

Comment: That clarifies things a little, but I still don't have a solid picture:

- There are 8 LEDs, but only 4 buttons.  Does each button affect 2 LEDs?
- If I understand your comments correctly, the pattern for each individual LED is: OFF, ON, BLINK SLOW, BLINK FAST.  Is that correct?  If so, and if each button drives 2 LEDS, but both don't change state at the same time, then what exactly is the pattern for each pair?

Comment: This is actually a little bit more complicated than that. 2 leds are Tx/Rx monitoring for IP transfer (like the LEDs on your ethernet connector). 2 others follow the same principle for RS232 transfer. 1 of the LED states whether the device is powered or not, the last three give an image of the internal state the controller is in. The state can change depending on the sequence off button pushed. However, one particular state could be Led1=OFF, Led2=SLOW, Led3=ON, and the next one (depending on the sequence of buttons) could be Led1=FAST, Led2=OFF and Led3=ON.

Comment: So you have the state change working as you desire, but the blinking is not in sync as you want?  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this didn't jump out at me sooner, but I think the problem is listed in your own question text, referring to the `toggleLeds` method:

> This one is called recursively through the self.after function, and at the end of the interaction function I have defined for each button.

When the program initially runs, I'm assuming that you call `toggleLeds` somewhere to kick off the initial pattern for the LEDs.  That sets up a single recursive loop via the `self.after` call at the end of the method.  However, if you *also* call that same method every time you click a button to change state, you're setting up a new loop with every button click, and each new loop may or may not be in sync with your initial loop.

There are a couple ways that I can think of to handle this possible conflict.  One is to avoid making new calls to `toggleLeds`, but that way there could be a delay between the button click and the new LED pattern.  If you don't mind that delay, that's probably the best solution.

If you want the light/blink pattern to change immediately, you need to interrupt the current loop and start a new one with the new light/blink states.  According to the [Tkinter reference produced by New Mexico Tech](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html), the `after` method:

> ...returns an integer “after identifier” that can be passed to the .after_cancel() method if you want to cancel the callback.

Here's how you could take advantage of that.  First make sure that you're storing that identifier when calling the `after` method:

```
self.after_id = self.after(self._FastBlinkTime, self.toggleLeds)
```

Then change your `toggleLeds` method definition to accept an optional "interrupt" argument, and to cancel the existing `after` loop if that argument is `True`:

```
def toggleLeds(self, interrupt=False):
    if interrupt:
        self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
    # Existing code follows
```

Finally, pass `True` to that argument when calling the method after a button has been clicked:

```
# Existing button processing code here
self.toggleLeds(interrupt=True)
```

With these changes in place, each button click would cancel the current `after` cycle and start a new one, preventing more than one cycle from running at once, which should keep the LEDs in sync.

Comment: Thanks Justin, indeed you are right. I had figured this was related to it but, since I am very new to tKinter, I had no idea on how to deal with the infinite loop that deals with the event handling. However, I found out that, by calling the toggleLeds function in my __init__ procedure only, ensuring that this procedure reads back the internal state of each led and adapts its output color, and having my button handling function updating the state of the Led does the the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome!  Feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel that it helped to solve the problem.